# How to get core dump from VIRTEX?

Tags: tex-core

Just out of curiosity, I stripped TeX source to a minimum from TeXLive build tree and compiled it successfully (it works in conjunction with `texlive-lang-english` package installed on Debian 10).

You can get it from github.com/igor-liferenko/tex and compile by just typing `make`.

Now I would like to create an executable with preloaded format (like in the old days). For this I need to produce a memory dump of the running executable. It is said [here](http://tex.loria.fr/texlive-htmldoc/web2c/web2c_toc.html#TOC15) that pressing C-\ must do the job. But it does not.

So, how does one produce a core dump? (Creating an executable out of it is not considered yet...)

Answer (score 4):

You could to compile with `-enable-auto-core-dump` as documented here

http://tex.loria.fr/texlive-htmldoc/web2c/web2c_3.html#SEC15

Rather than relying on a manual interrupt.

Comment: Going up one level to [table of contents](http://tex.loria.fr/texlive-htmldoc/web2c/web2c_toc.html), it looks like that link is documentation for web2c 7.2 from November 1997. And the corresponding section from the latest documentation of [2018 web2c](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/web2c.html#Three-programs) seems to have removed that part of the documentation… perhaps the option has been removed too? (Haven't actually tried it. :-) )